# How can I design a second widget with the QT-designer, when i have allready a widget at that position?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I want to make a gui with QT-creator 4.9.1. Designer. My window has 5 widgets, one of these widgets must be change his visibility everytime when the user select a other menu. For that i have made a widget namded workingarea inside my window and inside the workingarea-widget i have a second widget named workingplace0001. My problem is now, that i don't know how can i create the second widget, because i can't change the visibility from the workingplace0001 widget to false. Is there any possibility to change the visibility so i can create the workinplace0002 at that place or can't i use the Designer for that?

I must create 69 workingplaces

[image]

Comment: Look at `QStackedWidget`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect pls write an answer that i can close the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html). Just place it in on your main widget, then add number of pages you need, and then place every workingplace on every page of `QStackedWidget`. For changing current workingplace just change active page of `QStackedWidget`